# Converting entry to string in Python TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a simple logging app in TKinter. Basicly I need to compare an entry with a given string (proper pass). Unfortunatly, whenever I type the password, the result of the "entry.get()" method varries the input - printing it returns:

```
<bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>>
```

The code

```
def start_page():
    start_window = Tk()
    ent_1 = Entry(start_window)
    but_1 = Button(start_window, text='Login', command=partial(login, ent_1.get))
    but_1.grid(row=1,column=1)
    ent_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    start_window.mainloop()

def login(input_password):
    correct_password = 'password'
    if correct_password == input_password:
        coefficient_calc()
        start_window.destroy()
    else:
        print('You typed:', input_password)
        print('Please type the correct password.')
```

Any idea how to either convert it or "get" the entry in a desired form? I found few similar topics, but none answerred this particular issue.

Comment: Please provide a more complete, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that `entry_widget.get()` isn't the same thing as `entry_widget.get`.

Comment: Note that `start_window.destroy()` will also result in an error, as `start_window` is undefined as far as `login()` is concerned.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, it was just a typo (I'm using entry.get everywhere). 
In short words: "ent_1.get" returns:
    <bound method Entry.get of <tkinter.Entry object .!entry>> 
no matter what has been typed in. And I want to receive a literal input as string, so I can check if it matches the actual password.

Comment: @landogardner, smart note, I will try to fix it either by using "global" or remaking it into objective-oriented code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the definition of `login()` inside the scope of `start_window()` fixes the problem. No need to pass `ent_1` (and `start_window`) in to `login()`, and no need to use `functools.partial`:

```
def start_page():
    def login():
        input_password = ent_1.get()
        correct_password = 'password'
        if correct_password == input_password:
            coefficient_calc()
            start_window.destroy()
        else:
            print('You typed:', input_password)
            print('Please type the correct password.')

    start_window = Tk()
    ent_1 = Entry(start_window)
    but_1 = Button(start_window, text='Login', command=login)
    but_1.grid(row=1,column=1)
    ent_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    start_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: So the reason was `functools.partial` doesnt pass the parameters correctly?

Comment: You were passing the `get` method object itself to `login()`. What you really want is for the call to `get()` to be made when the button is pressed, which calls `login()`. So the simplest way to do this is to put the `get()` call inside `login()`. `functools.partial` was passing the parameters correctly, you were just giving it the wrong parameters :-)